# How to use Python to download file behind ASP.NET form?

Tags: python, asp.net, curl, .aspxauth

So, I already tried to do this with regular curl from the Linux shell, but it was not working (spoiler, it outputs the same error here in python).

Basically, I:

- GET the page
- Parse it and store __VIEWSTATE __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and __EVENTVALIDATION variables
- POST the form with these ASP variables and the values that I need.

My current code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import httpx
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser

client = httpx.Client()
url = "https://soportefirmadigital.com/sfdj/dl.aspx"
file = "ClientesLinux_DEB64_Rev25.zip"
desc = "Usuarios Linux (DEB 64bits)"
code = 1234

def main():
    # GET request, parse response
    html = HTMLParser(client.get(url).text)

    # Store ASPX values
    viewstategenerator  = html.css_first("input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR").attributes['value']
    eventvalidation     = html.css_first("input#__EVENTVALIDATION").attributes['value']
    viewstate           = html.css_first("input#__VIEWSTATE").attributes['value']

    # Fill form
    formdata = {
            "__EVENTTARGET": "ctl00$certContents$LinkButton3",
            "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
            "__LASTFOCUS": "",
            "__VIEWSTATE": viewstate,
            "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": viewstategenerator,
            "__EVENTVALIDATION": eventvalidation,
            "ctl00$certContents$hiddenISO": file,
            "ctl00$certContents$hidden_ISO_URL": "-",
            "ctl00$certContents$ddlInstaladores": desc,
            "ctl00$certContents$txtDescripcion": "",
            "ctl00$certContents$txtSerialNumber": code,
            "ctl00$certContents$hiddenABID": "",
            "ctl00$certContents$chkConfirmo": "on",
            }

    # Send form
    response = client.post(url, data=formdata)
    print(response.text)

main()
```

I expect this error (because I cant give out the actual ID):

```html
...
<span id="ctl00_certContents_lblErr" class="fieldErr" style="color:#C00000;">Su tarjeta tiene un número inválido, o bien, no está registrada para soporte.  En caso de duda contacte a su Institución Emisora.</span>
...
```

However, I get (this implies the serial number wasn't even stored):

```html
...
<span id="ctl00_certContents_lblErr" class="fieldErr"><font color="#C00000">Debe digitar el número de serie de su tarjeta</font></span>
...
```

Comment: Does a valid URL exist for the file, or is there a button click that downloads the file? Often in asp.net land, we don't have a public URL that translates to a given file folder for reasons of security. Thus, a button click is required on the download button, and code behind (c# or vb.net) goes and gets the file and sends it to the client. This means that you have to follow the exact same steps as if doing this manually, including that of any previous pages before hitting the current page. As code runs, then code variables are being setup.  You can't thus skip any manual steps here.

Comment: It is a button with href= `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$certContents$LinkButton3','')` I don't know if this is what you mean (I don't know anything abt asp.net). But do note I am actually able to download it from the terminal when using the curl command copied from browser's inspect.